# Regional problems with C# and SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Why would `dateTimePicker.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();` act differently on Windows 7 x64 PL, Windows Vista x32 PL and Windows XP PL with to my knowledge exact regional settings. I've found it out the hard way that i was doing this conversion prior to entering it to DB.

It was working fine on Windows 7 (my development machine), colleague VISTA system but it failed to work on Windows XP (day was switched with month all the time). Also on higher systems we have 2010-01-13 displayed on `ListView` while on his system he has 13-01-2010.

I imagine in my old code i may have more of those type conversions and i will have to go thru and verify it but i would like to know why it's behaving that way on same regional settings. I imagine I should never do conversions like that but I've learn it the hard way after a long time when it was working fine.

EDIT:

I was using it this way (commented out code that was causing troubles). Back in the old days I thought ToShortDateString was the only way to make sure to put it into DB without Time (since i was reading DateTimePicker). I know now that I should have used .Date on that DateTimePicker but I am smarter now that it did blow up on me. Here's the code:

```
    private static void sqlWpiszDaneSwieta(DateTime varData, string varDataNazwa) {
        //string varDataSwieto = varData.ToShortDateString();
        const string preparedCommand = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TypyDatySwiat]
                                           ([SwietaData]
                                           ,[SwietaNazwa])
                                     VALUES
                                           (@varData
                                           ,@varDataNazwa)";
          using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTime(Locale.sqlDataConnectionDetails))
        using (SqlCommand sqlWrite = new SqlCommand(preparedCommand, varConnection)) {
            sqlWrite.Prepare();
            sqlWrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varData", varData);
            sqlWrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@varDataNazwa", varDataNazwa);
            try {
                sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } catch (SqlException sqlEx) {
                if (sqlEx.Message.Contains("Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint")) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Dodanie podanego święta jest niemożliwe. Podane święto istnieje już w bazie danych!", "Bład", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                } else {
                    MessageBox.Show(sqlEx.ToString(), "Bład SQL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Bład", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

So i am not specifically asking for a way to do it. I know how to do it and that i can pass it using DateTime directly to db. Just that i would like to know why would it behave differently on 1 machine.

Comment: Why do you need to convert your `DateTime`'s to string anyway? If you're using parameters then you can pass in a `DateTime` instance directly. (And if you're not using parameters... why not??)

Comment: Well like i said it's my old code. Before i was doing lots of things I shouldn't. I am using parameters to pass DateTime properly now just since it worked correctly i didn't bother to change it. I've planned it to do it on cleaning up month where i will go and fix all the 'bad' things i did while learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> day was switched with month all the time

That sounds suspiciously like your colleague is using a UK locale on his XP machine, as that is the normal method for a date there.

But I'm more concerned about this:

> prior to entering it to DB.

If you're putting it into a DB, why are you calling `.ToShortDateString()`?  That smells like dynamic sql to me, and that means an sql injection vulnerability.  Instead of something like this:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO [MyTable] (MyDateColumn) VALUES (" + MyDateVar.ToShortDateString() + ")";
//sql command/connection code omitted from this sample
```

you need to do something like this:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO [MyTable] (MyDateColumn) VALUES (@MyDate)"
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("..connection string.."))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = MydateVar;

//remain code omitted
```

Notice the latter sample never converts the datetime variable to a string.  It will work no matter what locale your users have set.

Comment: I've edit main post to show how i used it (commented out the bad code). So i wasn't using dynamic sql yet having DateTime converted to ShortDateString() just before putting into DB made this happen. I know i shouldn't have do the conversion but i wasn't aware of it back then. Since i wanted to put only date i thought this is the best way of doing that at that time.

Comment: He isn't using UK settings. His XP is PL, he's using polish settings as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought it would be better to store things like date/times in a database using the Invariant Culture. It's when you get it out of the database to display it to a user that you should be concerned about regional settings.

Rather than storing a ShortDateString in the database, you should use `DateTime.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

To see (in the code) what Culture you're using, just use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name`.

Comment: I've just checked by using your code System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name that my system says pl-PL and win xp says exactly the same.

Comment: @MadBoy - what if you check `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat`?

Comment: System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern  = d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss  on both systems. If i do ToString() exactly what you wanted i get System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo as a result and i presume it's not what you wanted ;)

Comment: @MadBoy - No, I meant use the ToString overload on your DateTime object to convert it to a string using the Invariant culture. Then you won't get any culture-specific data in the database.

Comment: It's no problem. I wont be using it anymore. I'll use DateTime to DateTime most of the time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very much like regional settings.  I would check the regional settings of the accounts that the applications are running with to see if this offers an explanation.

As for dealing with the problem, the `ToBinary` method on `DateTime` offers a safe way of exporting the value in such a way that it can be later recreated.  Better still, considering this is going into a database, would be to pass in the value to the SQLCommand, as others have suggested.